# laravel guest middleware is redirecting to login page problem

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware, laravel-5.7, guest-executable

Here are my routes in web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('web.index');
})->name('index');

Route::get('/shop', 'WebController@index');
Route::get('/product/detail/{id?}', 'WebController@detail');

// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('cms', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('cms', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('cmsout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('cmsreg', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('cmsreg', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');

Route::fallback(function () {
    return response()->view( 'web.404', [], 404);
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::prefix('cat')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/save', 'CatController@index')->name('cat.save');
    Route::post('/save','CatController@save');
    Route::get('/manage','CatController@manage');
    Route::get('/edit/{id}','CatController@edit');
    Route::post('/edit','CatController@update');
    Route::get('/delete/{id}','CatController@delete');
});
```

But i can not access http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop because it is redirecting to http://127.0.0.1:8000/cms which is login page.

Why http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop is requiring me authentication? how can i define http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop is a guest url?

Answer (score 0):

Check `WebController` if you are forcing a middleware in its constructor